# Que es "./ " en python

Tags: python, funciones

Estoy reproduciendo un código y me he encontrado con esta función:

```
def plot_word_number_histogram(text):
    text.str.split().\
        map(lambda x: len(x)).\
        hist()
```

¿Alguien que me pueda explicar que es ".\"? ¿Es algún tipo de operador?

Comment: Cuando \ aparece al final de una línea, indica a Python que el comando no ha terminado y que continúa por la línea siguiente (es decir, de alguna forma \ hace "invisible" el retorno de carro que va tras él). El punto delante no forma parte de esto. Ese punto era parte de la expresión que quedó "partida" por el \

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La barra invertida `\` (que generalmente denota secuencias de escape) no es un operador, se usa en este caso para **romper una línea de código muy larga en varias**.

El `.` no tiene nada que ver con ello, es parte de la línea de código como tal, es simplemente la sintaxis de Python para el acceso a atributos (`objeto.atributo`), lo que se conoce como "dot notation".

Las líneas:

```
text.str.split().\
    map(lambda x: len(x)).\
    hist()
```

son exactamente lo mismo que:

```
text.str.split().map(lambda x: len(x)).hist()
```

Personalmente no me gusta, si puedo prefiero evitarlo. Yo suelo usar un paréntesis en su lugar, algo como:

```
def plot_word_number_histogram(text):
    (text.str.split()
             .map(lambda x: len(x))
             .hist()
            )
```

o:

```
def plot_word_number_histogram(text):
    (text.str.split()
         .map(lambda x: len(x))
         .hist()
        )
```

Además es la forma recomendada en [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). El único uso de `\` que se recomienda es para el caso de la sentencia `with` cuando queremos manejar varios contextos, por ejemplo:

```
with open('una/ruta/a/algun/sitio', "r") as input_file, \
     open('una/ruta/a/algun/otro/sitio', 'w') as output_fila:
```

Si no se usa una de las dos alternativas el intérprete tiene en cuanta la nueva línea y considera cada una como expresiones separadas.

Es típico también en el caso de cadenas no multi-línea:

```
cad = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vel "\
      "massa. Integer consectetur in elit faucibus pulvinar. Curabitur ut erat "\
      "eu mauris consequat posuere in ac purus. Fusce et nibh lorem."
```

igualmente debemos considerar el uso de paréntesis:

```
cad = (
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vel "
    "massa. Integer consectetur in elit faucibus pulvinar. Curabitur ut erat "
    "eu mauris consequat posuere in ac purus. Fusce et nibh lorem."
    )
```

**Por convención, las líneas en un módulo no deben superar los 79 caracteres para código y los 72 para cadenas de documentación.** Por lo tanto si la línea no supera los 79 caracteres no tiene sentido romperla, en éste caso lo correcto es:

```
def plot_word_number_histogram(text):
    text.str.split().map(lambda x: len(x)).hist()
```

Comment: Aclarado, muchas gracias.